Panel for flexible PCBs
I would like to know what parameters a panel for flexible PCBs should have. Can I use V-cuts or milling? What are the methods of depanelization? Should any part of the panel be rigid? Does anyone have a website or PDF that explains this topic?

What is "a panel for flexible PCBs"?

Googling "panelize FPC" (without the quote marks) will take you to various makers and their guidelines.
